# Registry Flag to Detect WinRE Enabled (Windows Recovery Environment)

Tags: windows, partitioning, recovery-partition

Does anyone know if there is a registry flag that I can use to detect if the Windows Recovery Environment is enabled or disabled?

Currently I'm using this script in the 'check requirements' section of my app deployment:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Detects if a Windows Recovery Partition needs to be setup

.DESCRIPTION
Uses powershell to check if WinRE is enabled

.NOTES
To be used in the Endpoint Manager and as the remidiation script
#>

try {
    $reagentcOutput = reagentc /info

    # Check if Recovery is already enabled
    if ($reagentcOutput -match "Enabled") {
        Write-Output "Enabled"
        exit 0
    } else {
        Write-Output "Not"
        exit 0
    }
  
  
}
catch {
    Write-Host "An Error occured! Hopefully this helps: $reagentcOutput"
    Write-Host "ERROR: at $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"
    Write-Error "Message: " $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "StackTrace: "
    Write-Host $_.Exception.StackTrace
    Write-Host ""
    exit 1
}    

exit 0
```

[Requirement evaluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEXsZ.png)

But the problem seems to be that either Intune does not evaluate the return of this script in the way I'm expecting or some other issue with the syntax or execution of the script. I wasn't able to find any examples of working requirement scripts.

Essentially, I just want to add a 'requirement' that WinRE is not already enabled before I go through the evaluation of installing my app (which configures partitions and moves the WinRE img file)

Comment: You would be better off trying to parse the partitions as I am unware of a registry that would indicate if the WinRE partition does or doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, in my environment, I cannot only parse the partitions because we have devices which sometimes have recovery partitions built, but don't have WinRE enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing the results of using the Reagentc command to disable
and enable WinRE, I have observed no registry modifications.
However, I have found differences inside the folder
`C:\Windows\System32\Recovery`.

There were basically two changes :

- When enabled, the file `Winre.wim` existed inside the folder.
  When disabled, the file was absent.
- The contents of the file `ReAgent.xml` have changed.

Here are the differences as regarding `ReAgent.xml`.
I include only the XML tags that have changed.

**Enabled**

```
  <WinreBCD id="{ee2fae51-df9e-11ea-8242-9cb6d0fa6b80}"/>
  <WinreLocation path="\Recovery\WindowsRE" id="0" offset="493646512128" guid="{a588d765-1bef-40cb-a90f-0b8cdafcd122}"/>
  <InstallState state="1"/>
  <ScheduledOperation state="5"/>
```

**Disabled**

```
  <WinreBCD id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
  <WinreLocation path="" id="0" offset="0" guid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
  <InstallState state="0"/>
  <ScheduledOperation state="4"/>
```

You should check the situation on your computers, and especially
the ones that don't have WinRE, but my guess is that the checks should
be similar to this :

- If the folder `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery` does not exist,
  or `ReAgent.xml` is missing, then WinRE is probably not installed.
- If the contents of
  `ReAgent.xml` have `WinreLocation path=""` or `InstallState state="0"`,
  then WinRE is probably disabled.

Comment: Note: I haven't worked out whether ReAgent.xml always exists, or requires the `/info` command to be created initially.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I hadn't thought to analyze the registry before and after enabling WinRE. Unfortunately, Intune is not capable of analyzing the contents of a file - they can only do checks on if the file exists, or the approximate size of the file in MB. This is why I was asking for a registry flag - Intune can do that natively.

To answer your question - for my environment at least, ReAgent is always present, but in an inactive configuration. When WinRE is enabled, the contents of that file change as you described.

Was there a tool you used to analyze the registry?

Comment: For tracing I used [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). For comparing the saved enabled/disabled folders I used [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/).