# WinRE not enabled after applying newly generated .WIM file

Tags: windows, dism, sysprep, wim, windows-re

I am trying to generate an reference image of Windows 10 pro. Everything works fine but the recovery tools are not enabled by default in the OOBE after applying the image despite the recovery tools being registered correctly (`reagentc /enable` during the OOBE does activate the recovery tools).

Is there a way to have WinRE enabled by default in the OOBE?

Additional information:

Windows 10 was installed to a HyperV VM with an .iso generated with the media creation tool.
To prepare, generate and apply the image I followed the following [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim?view=windows-11) by microsoft.

The WinRE.wim was copied from the recovery partition of the vm to the windows directory before generating the image.

Comment: Are you directly applying the WIM or using Windows Setup? If the latter, please post the custom answer file being used - as worded, the following quoted section is confusing since Windows Setup isn't used when applying a WIM directly: how is "_...`reagentc /enable` during the OOBE does activate the recovery tools._" being done?  If using an answer file, has it been verified WinRE is enabled by Windows Setup during Pass 7 [`oobeSystem`]?

Comment: If not using Windows Setup, the WinRE partition would be manually created via [Step 4](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) under "_How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?_", then enabled via [Step 4](https://superuser.com/a/1514869/529800) under "_To move WinRE to its own partition_"

Comment: The WIM is applied directly and and the recovery partition is generated the same as in your guide. I ran the command `reagentc /enable` in the command promt of the OOBE to check if the `Winre.wim` was copied and registered correctly, so there was no answer file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is normal and you should continue on doing
"reagentc /enable" during the OOBE.

You're installing a Windows image that contains Windows itself.
The recovery tools are located in a separate recovery partition
that needs to be created.

The Reagentc command to disable and enable WinRE, only copies
`Winre.wim` to the recovery partition when enabled, or from
the recovery partition to the Windows folder when disabled.
It may be found in `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery` or in
`C:\Recovery\OEM` folders, depending on the installed Windows version.

Your Windows image does not create the recovery partition,
it just applies Windows to its partition. Therefore
"reagentc /enable" is required to create the recovery partition
and to copy `Winre.wim` to it.

Comment: I am aware that `reagentc /enable` does not generate the `Winre.wim`. I guess I need to clarify more as I may have worded this badly.
The windows installation to generate the `.wim` was installed with a `.iso` that was generated by a windows media creation tool. As the `Winre.wim` was not in the directory `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery`, I mounted the recovery partition and copied it from there before generating the image.
The `Winre.wim` is then copied to the recovery partiton and registered by the installation script.
I will edit this in the question.

Comment: The winre.wim file is not enough. See https://superuser.com/a/1803522/8672

Comment: I tried modifying the image with the `Reagent.xml` so that it is identical with the one after using `Reagentc /enable` in the OOBE but the Recovery tools are still disabled after applying the image.

Comment: The link above contains empirical results that I found, since there is no documentation for it by Microsoft. It might not work or be enough for the OOBE environment, but I can't test this.